# Convergence of $\sum n!e^{1/n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum n!e^{1/n}$

I'm not sure how to prove whether this converges or diverges. I have a hunch that it converges, due to the factorial growing more slowly than an nth root, but I can't figure out how to prove it. The factorial keeps getting in the way.

I did try to take the natural log, but again I wasn't sure how to proceed with the ln. Additionally, I feel like there's a better, more elegant solution. How can I determine this series' convergence?

Comment: The terms (spectacularly) don't go to $0$. Automatic divergence.

Comment: $n!$ growing more slowly than the $n$th root? You need to rethink this.

Comment: My thought process was that this was similar to indeterminate cases like 0*infinity, where we don't know just by looking at it which way it will go. But I see now that I was (for whatever reason) computing this as e-->0, and this is why I thought it might be indeterminate. My mistake, now that it's pointed out I feel rather foolish for not noticing.

Comment: Note: e --> 0 makes no sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^{x}>1$ for any $x>0$, so $$n!e^{1/n}>n!$$

Not only the series does not converge, even the sequence of which it is the sum diverges as a factorial.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $e^{1/n} > 1.\,\,\,\,$